# Did Tony post guys outside of Happy's hospital room and have them require badges to get in?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-3

**Quote from Iron Man 3, emphasis my own:**

> [as Hogan lies in hospital critically injured, Tony is sat in his room
>   when a nurse walks in to check on Hogan]
>
> [...]
>
> Tony Stark: Uh...mind leaving that on?
>
> Happy's Nurse: Sure.
>
> [Tony rises from his seat]
>
> Tony Stark: Sunday night's PBS 'Downtown Abbey'. That's his show, he
>   thinks it's elegant.
>
> [he pauses for a moment]
>
> Tony Stark: One more thing...make sure everyone wears their badges.
>   He's a stickler for that sort of thing, plus **my guys won't let anyone
>   in without them.**
>
> [Tony turns to leave]

I just watched this scene and stopped to search the quote to make sure I heard it right:

Tony Stark says that his guys won't let anyone in without them, but earlier the badge thing (And Happy's security measures in general) didn't seem important at all to him and Pepper.

Perhaps I misunderstood this. I'm thinking by badges, Tony means his own security badges, not police badges.

**Did Tony post guys outside of Happy's hospital room and have them require security badges to get in?**

The thing that doesn't make sense to me is the idea of personal security in a public hospital, requiring personnel and visitors to wear badges from a personal security system.

Comment: Pretty evident from the excerpt you mentioned, isn't it?

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher Not.. extremely. It doesn't make very much sense the way I'm seeing it. Think about it; personal security in a public hospital, requiring personal security badges?

Comment: What makes you think it was a public hospital? And even it was, I don't see any reason why a billionaire superhero can't get his personal security team to guard one of his staff. Especially, in the aftermath of a suspected terror attack.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher but it's a respect thing, more than a reasonable thing. I think that's what made me curious

Answer (score 1):

Because the police had no reason to believe that Happy was in danger.

He was actually only at the site of the explosion because he was following the Henchman guy (can't remember his name), and managed to protect himself.

But at this point in time, whilst everyone was pretty sure that The Mandarin was the cause of the bomb, everyone thought Happy was just an innocent bystander.

There was not any evidence to suggest that he had seen anything or was connected to The Mandarin bombing.

Of course, Tony probably thought it was more than a coincidence that Happy happened to be there as one of The Mandarin's bombs went off, so on the off chance that Happy had learned something or been involved in some way, and that The Mandarin knew this, he thought it better to make sure his friend was safe from any repercussions.

This meant that he wanted to make sure that everything was done to protocol (checking badges etc.) to make sure no one tried to come in and kill Happy who may have been masquerading as a friend/police officer in order to get in his room.

He probably only added the 'He's a stickler for that sort of thing' to make sure the nurse didn't panic at the thought that a suicide bomber or a crazed gunman might come and try to kill Happy, and rather he was being cautious because he was the head of his security and would want it done that way.

Comment: Interesting points. But I would add that part of requiring those badges was probably also because *Happy* was such a "stickler" for them before. While *Tony* complained about that earlier, now that his friend was in serious hospital care, he wanted to do him the favour of encouraging his "badge-madness" a little, even if *Happy* won't really notice, in the same way as he wanted the nurse to let him watch *Downton Abbey*.